# R: dplyr solution for for-loop with initial conditions set

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, rcpp, purrr

I have a data which has 40 days of the year and some data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(day = 1:40,rain = runif(40,min = 0, max = 3), petc = runif(40, min = 0.3, max = 8),swc = runif(40, min = 27.01, max = 117.43))
```

I want to calculate another variable called aetc for each day which is calculated as follows:

```
SW.ini <- 2 # setting some initial values 
SW.max <- 5
SW.min <- 0
```

For day 1,

1) Determine a variable called `PAW(day1) = SW.ini + rain(day1)`

2) If `PAW(day1) >= SWC(day1), aetc(day1) = petc(day1)`;

```
If `PAW(day1) < SWC(day1), aetc(day1) = PAW(day1)/SWC(day1) * petc(day1)`
```

3) Check if `aetc(day1) > PAW(day1). If yes, aetc(day1) = paw(day1)`

4) Update `SW(day1) = SW.ini + rain(day1) - aetc(day1)`

5) If `SW(day1) > SW.max, SW(day1) = SW.max. Similarly if`SW(day1) < SW.min, SW(day1) = SW.min`

Repeat for day 2

1) Determine `PAW(day2) = SW(day1) + rain(day2)`
2) If `PAW(day2) >= SWC(day2), aetc(day2) = petc(day2)`;
   If `PAW(day2) < SWC(day2), aetc(day2) = PAW(day2)/SWC(day2) * petc(day2)`

3) Check if `aetc(day2) > PAW(day2)`. If yes, `aetc(day2) = paw(day2)`

4) Update `SW(day2) = SW(day1) + rain(day2) - aetc(day2)`

5) If `SW(day2) > SW.max, SW(day2) = SW.max. Similarly if`SW(day2) < SW.min, 
 SW(day2) = SW.min`

Here's my elegant for loop to do this:

```
      df$PAW <- NA
      df$aetc <- NA
      df$SW <- NA

      df$PAW[1] <- SW.ini + df$rain[1]

      df$aetc[1] <- ifelse(df$PAW[1] >= df$swc[1], df$petc[1],(df$PAW[1]/df$swc[1])*df$petc[1])
      df$aetc[1] <- ifelse(df$aetc[1] > df$PAW[1], df$PAW[1], df$aetc[1])
      df$SW[1] <- SW.ini + df$rain[1] -  df$aetc[1]
      df$SW[1] <- ifelse(df$SW[1] > SW.max, SW.max, ifelse(df$SW[1] < 0, 0,df$SW[1]))

      for (day in 2:nrow(df)){

        df$PAW[day] <- df$SW[day - 1] + df$rain[day]
        df$aetc[day] <- ifelse(df$PAW[day] >= df$swc[day], df$petc[day], (df$PAW[day]/df$swc[day]) * df$petc[day])
        df$aetc[day] <- ifelse(df$aetc[day] > df$PAW[day], df$PAW[day],df$aetc[day])
        df$SW[day] <- df$SW[day - 1] + df$rain[day] -  df$aetc[day]
        df$SW[day] <- ifelse(df$SW[day] > SW.max,SW.max, ifelse(df$SW[day] < 0, 0,df$SW[day]))
      }
```

My problem is that this is just one year of data and I want run it for multiple years.

```
      set.seed(123)
      df <- data.frame(year = 1980:2015, day = rep(1:40, each = 36),rain = 
      runif(40*36,min = 0, max = 3), petc = runif(40*36, min = 0.3, max = 8),swc = runif(40*36, min = 27.01, max = 117.43))
```

So I wanted to do something like

```
                df %>% group_by(year) # and then run the above function for each year.
```

Is there a dplyr or any other solution to this?

Thank you

Comment: I think you are more likely to receive help if you provide a truly minimal example, e.g. 2-3 days * the number of 'if-scenarios' necessary, not more, not less. Also provide the corresponding desired output. Then it's much easier to grasp the logic and to try out code. Cheers.

Comment: okay. Let me figure out the right reproducible example.

Comment: You have several answers to your question. What do you expect from an answer "worthy of an additional bounty"?

Comment: I started the bounty to give bounty to answer that I accepted. I didn't know it takes 24 hours before I can award the bounty to the below answer. Sorry I didn't know how the bounty system works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Note: I originally posted this answer on your follow up question, [R: for loop within a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136712/r-for-loop-within-a-foreach-loop/49140442#49140442), but after seeing this one, it seems this answer is far more relevant here. *(I don't address anything related to parallelizing in my answer, which was the topic of your follow up)*.

### Using `Rcpp` and `data.table`

Compiling the logic with C++ and applying it by group using data.table grouping operations gives a ~2,000x speed-up from your baseline, far greater than you might hope to get by parallelizing.

On your original example, which had **39,420,000 rows**, this executes on my machine in **1.883 seconds**; and on the revised one with **28,800 rows**, this executes in **0.004 seconds**

```
library(data.table)
library(Rcpp)
```

Define and compile a `C++` function, `CalcSW()` inline in the R script:

*One note: counting in `C`/`C++` starts at `0`, unlike `R`, which starts at `1`-- that's why the indices are different here*

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
List CalcSW(NumericVector SW_ini,
            NumericVector SW_max,
            NumericVector rain,
            NumericVector swc,
            NumericVector PETc) {

  int n = SW_ini.length();
  NumericVector SW(n);
  NumericVector PAW(n);
  NumericVector aetc(n);

  double SW_ini_glob = SW_ini[0];
  double SW_max_glob = SW_max[0];

  SW[0] = SW_ini_glob;
  PAW[0] = SW[0] + rain[0];

  if (PAW[0] > swc[0]){
    aetc[0] = PETc[0];
  } else {
    aetc[0] = PAW[0]/swc[0]*PETc[0];
  }

  if (aetc[0] > PAW[0]){
    aetc[0] = PAW[0];
  }

  SW[0] = SW[0] + rain[0] - aetc[0];

  if(SW[0] > SW_max_glob){
    SW[0] = SW_max_glob;
  }

  if(SW[0] < 0){
    SW[0] = 0;
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {

    PAW[i] = SW[i-1] + rain[0];

    if (PAW[i] > swc[i]){
      aetc[i] = PETc[i];
    } else {
      aetc[i] = PAW[i]/swc[i]*PETc[i];
    }

    if (aetc[i] > PAW[i]){
      aetc[i] = PAW[i];
    }

    SW[i] = SW[i-1] + rain[i] - aetc[i];

    if(SW[i] > SW_max_glob){
      SW[i] = SW_max_glob;
    }

    if(SW[i] < 0){
     SW[i] = 0;
    }
  }
  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("SW") = SW,
                            Rcpp::Named("PAW") = PAW,
                            Rcpp::Named("aetc") = aetc);
}')
```

Create data.table

```
df <- data.table(loc.id = rep(1:10, each = 80*36), 
                 year = rep(rep(1980:2015, each = 80), times = 10),
                 day = rep(rep(1:80, times = 36),times = 10),
                 rain = runif(10*36*80, min = 0 , max = 5),
                 swc = runif(10*36*80,min = 0, max = 50),
                 SW_max = rep(runif(10, min = 100, max = 200), each = 80*36),
                 SW_ini = runif(10*36*80),
                 PETc = runif(10*36*80, min = 0 , max = 1.3),
                 SW = as.numeric(NA),
                 PAW = as.numeric(NA), 
                 aetc = as.numeric(NA))

setkey(df, loc.id, year, day)
```

Execute the function `CalcSW()` on the `df` for each combination of `loc.id` and `year`, assign returned values to the three columns simultaneously:

```
system.time({
  df[,  c("SW","PAW","aetc") := CalcSW(SW_ini,
                                       SW_max,
                                       rain,
                                       swc,
                                       PETc), keyby = .(loc.id, year)]
})
```

...

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.004   0.000   0.004
```

Results:

```
head(df)
```

...

```
   loc.id year day       rain       swc   SW_max     SW_ini      PETc       SW      PAW       aetc
1:      1 1980   1 0.35813251 28.360715 177.3943 0.69116310 0.2870478 1.038675 1.049296 0.01062025
2:      1 1980   2 1.10331116 37.013022 177.3943 0.02742273 0.4412420 2.125335 1.396808 0.01665171
3:      1 1980   3 1.76680011 32.509970 177.3943 0.66273062 1.1071233 3.807561 2.483467 0.08457420
4:      1 1980   4 3.20966558  8.252797 177.3943 0.12220454 0.3496968 6.840713 4.165693 0.17651342
5:      1 1980   5 1.32498191 14.784203 177.3943 0.66381497 1.2168838 7.573160 7.198845 0.59253503
6:      1 1980   6 0.02547458 47.903637 177.3943 0.21871598 1.0864713 7.418750 7.931292 0.17988449
```

I'm not 100% positive I implemented your logic perfectly, but the logic should be pretty straightforward to tweak where I may have missed something, I implemented it in a very similar manner to how you laid it out.

---

One other note: It's way easier to write `C++` with auto-indenting and code highlighting *(whether you're using RStudio or Emacs)* you get if you create a separate file, named something like `TestCode.cpp`formatted like below.

Then, you can either use `Rcpp::sourceCpp("TestCode.cpp")` to compile your function in your R Script, or you can copy and paste everything except for the first three lines as a character string into as an argument of `Rcpp::cppFunction()` like I did above.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List CalcSW(NumericVector SW_ini,
                     NumericVector SW_max,
                     NumericVector rain,
                     NumericVector swc,
                     NumericVector PETc) {

  int n = SW_ini.length();
  NumericVector SW(n);
  NumericVector PAW(n);
  NumericVector aetc(n);

  double SW_ini_glob = SW_ini[0];
  double SW_max_glob = SW_max[0];

  SW[0] = SW_ini_glob;
  PAW[0] = SW[0] + rain[0];

  if (PAW[0] > swc[0]){
    aetc[0] = PETc[0];
  } else {
    aetc[0] = PAW[0]/swc[0]*PETc[0];
  }

  if (aetc[0] > PAW[0]){
    aetc[0] = PAW[0];
  }

  SW[0] = SW[0] + rain[0] - aetc[0];

  if(SW[0] > SW_max_glob){
    SW[0] = SW_max_glob;
  }

  if(SW[0] < 0){
    SW[0] = 0;
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {

    PAW[i] = SW[i-1] + rain[0];

    if (PAW[i] > swc[i]){
      aetc[i] = PETc[i];
    } else {
      aetc[i] = PAW[i]/swc[i]*PETc[i];
    }

    if (aetc[i] > PAW[i]){
      aetc[i] = PAW[i];
    }

    SW[i] = SW[i-1] + rain[i] - aetc[i];

    if(SW[i] > SW_max_glob){
      SW[i] = SW_max_glob;
    }

    if(SW[i] < 0){
      SW[i] = 0;
    }
  }
  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("SW") = SW,
                            Rcpp::Named("PAW") = PAW,
                            Rcpp::Named("aetc") = aetc);
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I have just started to learn Rcpp C++ and nice to see another example! I have huge projects im working on and need the speed for some functions!

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your code in another for loop and save each years df in a list:

```
library(tidyverse)
lst <- vector("list", length(unique(df$year)))
for (i in seq_along(unique(df$year))) {
    df_year <- df %>% filter(year == unique(df$year)[[i]])

    # rest of code with df_year replacing df

    lst[[i]] <- df_year
}
final_df <- bind_rows(lst)
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to avoid running a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `data.table` illustration from Matt is a very good illustration of how fast `data.table` can be because it does the calculations in place with no copies and moving around of data.

However, to answer the crux of your question about using pipes, you can use `group_by` along with `do` to accomplish what you are after (albeit much slower than `data.table`)

Below I set up the same dummy data Matt did. Then I use your function (but with the case fixed on `PETc`). It's not fast, but it's pretty easy to follow.

```
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:10, each = 80*36), 
                 year = rep(rep(1980:2015, each = 80), times = 10),
                 day = rep(rep(1:80, times = 36),times = 10),
                 rain = runif(10*36*80, min = 0 , max = 5),
                 swc = runif(10*36*80,min = 0, max = 50),
                 SW_max = rep(runif(10, min = 100, max = 200), each = 80*36),
                 SW_ini = runif(10*36*80),
                 PETc = runif(10*36*80, min = 0 , max = 1.3) 
                 )

my_fun <- function(df){
  SW.ini <- 2 # setting some initial values 
  SW.max <- 5
  SW.min <- 0

  df$PAW <- NA
  df$aetc <- NA
  df$SW <- NA

  df$PAW[1] <- SW.ini + df$rain[1]

  df$aetc[1] <- ifelse(df$PAW[1] >= df$swc[1], df$PETc[1],(df$PAW[1]/df$swc[1])*df$PETc[1])
  df$aetc[1] <- ifelse(df$aetc[1] > df$PAW[1], df$PAW[1], df$aetc[1])
  df$SW[1] <- SW.ini + df$rain[1] -  df$aetc[1]
  df$SW[1] <- ifelse(df$SW[1] > SW.max, SW.max, ifelse(df$SW[1] < 0, 0,df$SW[1]))

  for (day in 2:nrow(df)){

    df$PAW[day] <- df$SW[day - 1] + df$rain[day]
    df$aetc[day] <- ifelse(df$PAW[day] >= df$swc[day], df$PETc[day], (df$PAW[day]/df$swc[day]) * df$PETc[day])
    df$aetc[day] <- ifelse(df$aetc[day] > df$PAW[day], df$PAW[day],df$aetc[day])
    df$SW[day] <- df$SW[day - 1] + df$rain[day] -  df$aetc[day]
    df$SW[day] <- ifelse(df$SW[day] > SW.max,SW.max, ifelse(df$SW[day] < 0, 0,df$SW[day]))
  }
  return(df)
}


library(tictoc)
library(tidyverse)


tic()
df  %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  do(my_fun(.)) -> 
  out
toc()
#> 5.075 sec elapsed
```